# jQuery Tokeninput save combination of ID and secound Value as internal ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I get an JSON Array like this:

```
[{"type":"user","id":"12","name":"Name of User"},{"type":"group","id":"9","name":"Name of UserGroup"}]
```

The Backend returns an JSON Array with Name, Id and the Type (User or Group).

Is there any way to manipulate the id before there is inputted to the input field, for example to

```
 type+"_"+id
```

?

Actually, I'm using this to intializie tokenInput:

```
$("input#id").tokenInput(apiURL+"search.php", {
                defaultValue:"User or User Group",
                hintText:"Fill in User or User Group name.",
                noResultsText:"nothing found.",
                searchingText:"Searching...",
                queryParam:"search",
                crossDomain:false,
                tokenLimit:5,
                preventDuplicates:true,
                minChars:3,
                resultsFormatter:function(item) {
                    return "<li><img src="+((item.type=="user") ? "contact" : "contact_group")+ ".png\"/>"+item.name+"</li>";
                }
            });
```

---

With the help of Rory McCrossan I got it work. Change the id into the resultsFormatter Method will do the trick:

```
resultsFormatter:function(item) {
     if (item.id.indexOf("_") == -1)
     {
           item.id = item.type+"_"+item.id;
     }

     return "<li><img src="+((item.type=="user") ? "contact" : "contact_group")+ ".png\"/>"+item.name+"</li>";
```

}

The "if (item.id.indexOf (...))" is nessecary, because the tokenInput chaches the entries, and if you search for the same string, the id already have the type+"_" prefix and would get it a secound/third/... time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
resultsFormatter: function(item) {
    var itemId = item.type + "_" + item.id;
    return "<li id='" + itemId + "'><img src="+((item.type=="user") ? "contact" : "contact_group")+ ".png\"/>"+item.name+"</li>";
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. But I'm using jQuery with tokenInput plugin (http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

Comment: I have edited my question to give you more informations. Your snipped won't work for me, because i don't initialize the tokenInput with data, it have to look for it 'live' when the user is looking for an string as user or group name.

Comment: The output is still "12" or "9" and not "user_12" or "group_9".

Comment: Another update. Could you post the `resultsFormatter` as you are using it. Thanks

Comment: I've found the answer with your help. Thank you. I updated my Question and added the right answer.